# (Noob Question) Why is checking if the user is the author of a blog post completely different in .py and .html files?

Tags: html, django

in views.py

```
if self.request.user == post.author
```

in .html

```
{%  if object.author == user  %}
```

Can someone provide an explanation or a place that explains why this is so different? My understand is that `{% /// %}` runs the python code within it.

Why in the html does it refer to only 'object.author' instead of 'post.author? How is object specific enough?

Comment: Because they're in different places?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's exactly the same. If you change context object name from default `object` to `post` and get user from context request in templates, html tag changes to:

```
{% if post.author == request.user %}
```

which is the same.